# xcode, how to use storyboard reference connect inner view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In screen shot one I have a view controller connect with storyboard reference.

In screen shot two which is the reference storyboard, have the initial view controller **one** and an inner view controller **two**.

How do I connect the inner vc **two** with reference?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: 
Add id to the view controller which is inner a storyboard(you want to the segue connect with).

Step 2:
In storyboard reference, add the id of the VC you want to connect with.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connect Multiple storyBoard Using reference : [**See My tutorial**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-use-multiple-storyboard-using.html)

I have provide all steps, How to connect one StoryBoard with Another using reference.

Comment: Your tutorial will be useless when the link breaks. Why not post it here as a proper answer?

Comment: I have read your post and i do not think it can give me a solution